Turning Nearest Neighbour Distribution of Poisson Scatter Theorem to Rayleigh Distribution By Multiplying Constant
Consider a Poisson random scatter of points in a plane with mean intensity $\phi$ per unit area. Let R be the distance from 0 to closest point of the scatter.
Show that $\sqrt{2\phi\pi}$R has the Rayleigh distribution.
I get $F_R(r) = 1 - e^{-\phi \pi r^2}$.This is the CDF of an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda = \phi\pi r$.
I get that $2\phi\pi \times E[R] = \frac{2}{r}$ which in turn means that new distribution will have CDF $F_{r\phi\pi R} = 1 - e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2} $, due to the expectation of an exponential distribution W with rate $\lambda$ being $E[W] = \frac{1}{\lambda}$. This is indeed the CDF of a Rayleigh distribution.
However, I don't get how taking the square root of $2\phi\pi$ gives us the correct final distribution? What am I missing here?

Okay, I just realized I needed a different approach. This is a common problem shown for undergrads studying probability theory, so instead of deleting the question I will just answer it myself.
The key is to consider the distribution
$R_1 = \sqrt{2 \phi \pi}R$, such that
$P(R_1 \leq r_1) 
= P( \sqrt{2 \phi \pi} R \leq r_1) 
= P(R \leq \frac{r_1}{ \sqrt{2 \phi \pi}} ) 
= 1 - e^{-\phi \pi (\frac{r_1}{ \sqrt{ 2 \phi \pi}})^2} 
= 1 - e^{-\frac{1}{2} r_1^2}$
Which is exactly the CDF of the Rayleigh distribution!
